# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') when trying to use my own built package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs, rollupjs

I am trying to build a package in npm using rollup, and babel. When I am using my package after building and publishing in github package I am getting the above error. I am using storybook to test the component. Not getting this error though when I am trying to use it under storybook page.

**rollup.config.js**

```
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      postcss(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.(css|less|scss)$/],
  },
];
```

**babel.config.js**

```
    presets: [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ],
  };
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Default
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    // Added
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
  "name": "@piupaulgit/react-accessible-custom-select",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/react-accessible-custom-select",
    "access": "public"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple template for a custom React component library",
  "scripts": {
    "rollup": "rollup -c",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "author": "Piu paul",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.0",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.1.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.6",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^7.2.1",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^2.60.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.43.5",
    "sass-loader": "^12.3.0",
    "storybook": "^7.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.2",
    "minimatch": "^9.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```